# 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to interpret data I am planning to send betweeen machines with a chosen target where I will send the data to and the data the following code is supposed to do this(the target is a number of any length and has to start with a "/") I know the whole code isn't great and I am probably using wrong names for pretty much everything but I hope with a bit of help it will work

```py
def Interpret(command):
    if(command[0] != "/"):
        return "ERROR"
    o = 1
    targetstr = []
    while(command[o] != " "):
        targetstr.append[command[o]]
        o = o + 1
    try:
        "".join(targetstr)
        target = int(targetstr)
    except:
        return "ERROR"
    data = []
    for i in range(o + 1, len(command)):
        data.append(command[i])
    return [target, "".join(data)]
```

everytime I run the code I get this error message:
    targetstr.append[command[o]]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
(pbviously it is supposed to give me an array with the target and the data)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo since `append` is correctly called in one of the two occurrences.

Comment: `"".join(targetstr)` doesn't do anything useful; it leaves `targetstr` unchanged while ignoring the return value of `join`. Did you mean `targetstr = "".join(targetstr)`? (Also, `targets = []` would be a better name to use for the *list* of targets; it's not a string yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.append()` is a function

```
targetstr.append[command[o]]
```

Should be

```
targetstr.append(command[o])
```

The reason why you are getting that particular error is that when you use the square bracket syntax `foo[bar]` python is actually calling `foo.__getitem__(bar)` and the append method does not have the attribute/method `__getitem__`